# Describing the fact that the mentioned subject is not in the area of your responsibility

Tags: phrase-request

> -- What can you tell me about Johnson's progress? Is his professionalism growing?
>
> -- How can I say anything about him? On the very second day of his employment, you moved him to the sales department and I have never
>   seen him since that time. His progress is **out of the scope of my
>   reference**.

Is "out of the scope of my reference" idiomatic?

Comment: Your title and question body don't really match up.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Got it! Just re-phrased the title using your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also say

> John has been operating *outside my bailiwick*.

Your **bailiwick** is the "area" (e.g. sphere of activity or operations) for which you have responsibility.

> John hasn't really been *on my turf* since you reassigned him early on.

Your **turf** is an informal name for the "place" (broadly construed) you're responsible for, the one you feel possessive about, the one over which you'd assert your prerogatives, such as a department in an organization, a neighborhood, a sales region, etc.

You could also say

> John has been outside my purview.

Your **purview** is your scope of responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

I'd totally understand *"Out of the scope of my reference"*, but I don't think I've ever heard it before. It comes across as a little awkward, but pretty much fine IMO.

Your title says "not your field to comment on" and in that case I would normally use *"not my field of expertise"*, but that clearly isn't what you want in the example.

I think instead you just want to convey that you shouldn't be expected to know anything about his progress. In which case you could use:

> How can I say anything about him? On the very second day of his employment, you moved him to the sales department and I have never seen him since that time. **I wouldn't know anything about his progress.**